# awk print FILENAME if field after regex is less than

Tags: awk

I would like to print the FILENAME if field after regex is less than 150. This is the code I came up with. But the output produces nothing.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=='price' && $(i+1) < 150){print FILENAME} } }" files* > filenames
```

Comment: That's not looking for a field after a regex, it's looking for a field after a **string**. It's very important to understand the difference. Post some sample input and expected output and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in your command (missing quote at the end). I did change it this way:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="price" && $(i+1) < 150){print FILENAME} } }' files* > filenames
```

And... as far as I can test ... it works.

Comment: Depends what "works" means. That probably fixes the OPs code but I can imagine various input sets where it'd probably produce undesirable results (e.g. `price` appears more than once on a line or the field after `price` can be a string or there's thousands of fields after `price` or ....). Until the OP shows us at least a few lines of sample input and expected output and clarifies his requirements, who knows....?

Comment: Yes indeed that was it: "Starting price" - "Price Realised" So now I got the correct code: awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /Starting/ && $(i+1) ~ /price/ && $(i+2) <= 150) print FILENAME, $(i+2) }'